# Mongodb: update array of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection named **products** in which I want to update the code which have the empty field under **options.stores.code**
structure is as follow:-

```
{
"_id": ObjectId(),
"sku": "V4696-DR-V33",
"options": [
    {
        "sku": "8903689984338",
        "stores": [
            {
                "code": "AND1",
                "zipcode": "110070",
                "inventory": -5000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND2",
                "zipcode": "201010",
                "inventory": -5000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND3",
                "zipcode": "411001",
                "inventory": -5000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND4",
                "zipcode": " 700020",
                "inventory": -5000
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "sku": "1742564789",
        "stores": [
            {
                "code": "AND1",
                "zipcode": "110070",
                "inventory": -5000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND2",
                "zipcode": "201010",
                "inventory": -5000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND3",
                "zipcode": "411001",
                "inventory": -5000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND8",
                "zipcode": " 700020",
                "inventory": -5000
            }
        ],
    },

]
```

}

Want to update the **inventory**, which have the same **code**.

Comment: you may find answer here  
 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733790/want-to-update-array-of-array-object-value-in-mongo)

Comment: Thanks  for the reply.
I have checked the query is working only for the single object inside the array.but not for the all the matched element.

Answer (score 0):

For updating empty store codes:

```
db.products.update({"code":""},{$set:{"code":"new value"}}
```

Comment: This is normal update, but it will not the way I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

using the python script use any loop for this update........... and made a slight modification------{$set:{"options.(loop variable).stores.$.inventory":}} this can help for query

Comment: can we do with mongo query without using any loop,
as I have many records to update.

Comment: there is no direct way to update using mongo query, u have to use any loop.

Comment: k thanks will work on this solution and post you the update : ) Thanks