# Want to Update Array of Array Object Value in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the following MongoDB document:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId(),
"sku": "V4696-DR-V33",
"options": [
    {
        "sku": "8903689984338",
        "stores": [
            {
                "code": "AND1",
                "zipcode": "110070",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND2",
                "zipcode": "201010",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND3",
                "zipcode": "411001",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND4",
                "zipcode": " 700020",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND5",
                "zipcode": "110015",
                "inventory": -1000
            }
        ],
        "price": 2199,
        "_id": ObjectId(),
        "size": "14"
    },
    {
        "sku": "1742564789",
        "stores": [
            {
                "code": "AND1",
                "zipcode": "110070",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND2",
                "zipcode": "201010",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND3",
                "zipcode": "411001",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND4",
                "zipcode": " 700020",
                "inventory": -1000
            },
            {
                "code": "AND5",
                "zipcode": "110015",
                "inventory": -1000
            }
        ],
        "price": 2199,
        "_id": ObjectId(),
        "size": "14"
    },

]
}
```

I want to update each inventory value where code value is "AND1" . 
I want query in mongo query or any python script to update whole document with nested value.
I am very Stuck with This Issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change all the array elements in a mongodb document to a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610663/how-to-change-all-the-array-elements-in-a-mongodb-document-to-a-certain-value)

Comment: I wan't mongo query to direct update to my All Inventory value. U have any idea about this???

Comment: The duplicate shows how you can do it. That is all..

Comment: In my case where condition at  "option.store.code" level then what should i have to do??

Comment: @AsheshKhatri have you tried by using [find and modify](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify)?

Comment: @Smart003 wrong! findAndModify  has nothing to do here.

Comment: @AsheshKhatri is it so difficult to understand how the duplicate answer works?

Comment: @Smart003 I have use this query :
db.runCommand(
   {
     findAndModify: "new_product",
     query: { "options.stores.$.code": "172" },
     update: { $inc: { "options.stores.$.inventory": -1000 } }
   }
 )
But not update the record.

Comment: @AsheshKhatri see the below answer

Answer (score 1):

try the following query for update

```
db.stack.update({"options.0.stores":{$elemMatch:{code:"AND1"}}},{$set:{"options.0.stores.$.inventory":200}})
```

for check i'll update with images....
[image]

i had taken the your data as example

now i had used the above query 
 db.stack.update({"options.0.stores":{$elemMatch:{code:"AND1"}}},{$set:{"options.0.stores.$.inventory":200}})

then the result is shown in the following image
[image]

i had update the inventory to 200 where code:"AND1"

see the changes.

Comment: here I have multiple array in options in which I have similar "store.code" how will it work in this case
{
    "options": [
        {
            "sku": "8903689984338",
            "stores": [
                {
                    "code": "AND1",
                    "inventory": -1000
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "sku": "1742564789",
            "stores": [
                {
                    "code": "AND1",
                    "inventory": -1000
                }
            ],
        },
    ]
}

Comment: @AsheshKhatri as per the above query all the documents which matches the conditions will be update.

Comment: As you mentioned in the question "I want to update each inventory value where code value is "AND1". hence the above query will satisfy the statement

Comment: but i have multiple json object in "options" then i can't use "options.0.stores"  in this case i m struggling!! u have any other way to resolve this query ??

Comment: can you give the entire structure of your collection. if i know the collection structure i can help on this

Comment: How do i share with u ??

Comment: the above query will be update the value which was fetched first.....
since you are using the python script use any loop for this update...........
and made a slight modification------{$set:{"options.(loop variable).stores.$.inventory":<value>}}

Comment: ya this can work but this i m looking for direct update using mongo query